# ToggleGroup with ToggleButtons JavaFX

Tags: javafx

How do I deselect all `ToggleButtons` in a `ToggleGroup` in JavaFX? There doesn't seem to be a `clearSelection()` feature like there was in Swing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either do

```
toggleGroup.selectToggle(null);
```

or, if you know something is selected,

```
toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().setSelected(false);
```

Comment: When I do this, the blue halo from being focused still shows. Do you know how to remove that, too?

Comment: The only way I know would be to move focus to some other node.