# How can I make a ToggleButton look like a RadioButton without changing its behavior?

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button, javafx-8, togglebutton

Sort of the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786146). I have a group of ToggleButtons that I want to look like RadioButtons, while maintaining the ability to unselect all of them at once. How can I accomplish this? The "opposite" of the accepted answer on that question doesn't work in this case; it just removes all styling of the buttons, leaving only their labels.

```
//this doesn't work
ToggleButton button=new ToggleButton("Toggle me!");
button.getStyleClass().remove("toggle-button");
button.getStyleClass().add("radio-button");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*ToggleGroup with ToggleButtons JavaFX*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23462754/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this style manipulations. `RadioButton` class extends `ToggleButton`, so you can just do this:

```
ToggleButton button = new RadioButton("Toggle me!");
```

### Edit

To keep `ToggleButton` behavior in `ToggleGroup`(be able to unselect), you can use your implementation of `RadioButton` with overriden `fire()` method with logic like in `ToggleButton` class:

```
public static class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton {
    public MyRadioButton() {
    }

    public MyRadioButton(String text) {
        super(text);
    }
    @Override
    public void fire() {
        if (!isDisabled()) {
            setSelected(!isSelected());
            fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did state that I need to "maintain the ability to unselect all of them at once." RadioButtons do not have this behavior, while ToggleButtons do. A RadioButton will not allow itself to be unselected while part of a ToggleGroup.

Comment: @RyanHilbert ye, you right, `RadioButton` has overriden `fire()` method. See my edit to solve this.